# The following patterns were never triggered in this artifact inclusion filter: o 'com.alibaba:dubbo

Tags: maven, maven-assembly-plugin

Following are the contents for the assembly.xml

> ```
> <assembly>
> <id>jar-with-dependencies</id>
> <formats>
>     <format>jar</format>
> </formats>
> <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
> <dependencySets>
>     <dependencySet>
>         <unpack>true</unpack>
>   <unpackOptions>
>     <excludes>
>         <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
>         <exclude>META-INF/**</exclude>
>     </excludes>
>   </unpackOptions>
>         <includes>
>             <include>com.alibaba:dubbo</include>
>             <include>commons-codec:commons-codec</include> 
>              <include>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient</include>                               
>              <include>org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore</include>
>              <include>org.apache.commons:commons-csv</include>
>         </includes>
>     </dependencySet>
> </dependencySets>
> ```

I have added following dependency to the pom.xml -

> ```
> <!-- Dubbo -->
>     <dependency>
>         <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
>         <artifactId>dubbo</artifactId>
>         <version>2.5.9</version>
>         <scope>provided</scope>
>     </dependency>
>    <build>
>     <plugins>
>         <plugin>
>             <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
>             <version>3.0.0</version>
>             <executions>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>prod-jar</id>
>                     <phase>package</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>single</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <descriptors>
>                             <descriptor>assembly.xml</descriptor>
>                         </descriptors>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>jar-for-testcase</id>
>                     <phase>package</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>single</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <descriptors>
>                             <descriptor>assembly_test.xml</descriptor>
>                         </descriptors>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>                 <execution>
>                     <id>pkg</id>
>                     <phase>package</phase>
>                     <goals>
>                         <goal>single</goal>
>                     </goals>
>                     <configuration>
>                         <appendAssemblyId>false</appendAssemblyId>
>                         <descriptors>
>                             <descriptor>pkg_assembly.xml</descriptor>
>                         </descriptors>
>                     </configuration>
>                 </execution>
>             </executions>
>         </plugin>
>     </plugins>
> </build>
> ```

When I run maven install, I am getting the warning and my code doesn't work. But if I run the code directly without creating the jar then it works just fine. So there is something wrong with the jar that get created. Debugging this, I came across this warning. But I am unable to understand what wrong am I doing. According to my understanding the include tag should contain group-id:artifact-id. I am doing this but still I am getting the warning. Can someone put some light on what am I missing here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Resolved the warning with the following replacement

> ```
>  <include>com.alibaba:dubbo:jar:</include>
> ```

Just for reference, following is the long pattern  *groupId:artifactId:type:classifier*

Comment: is the last colon ":" necessary?

Comment: @Gaurav No, the last colon is specifying an empty classifier which is the default. See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html for more information on Maven coordinates